# Can't make Firebase remote config conditions work based in the country

Tags: mobile, firebase-remote-config

We have added a condition in Firebase remote config. The user will receive different json data for a particular field depending on the country.

The issue we are experiencing is that even if I'm behind a VPN and select France as my country. The VPN response is correct, Firebase still says I'm in Spain (real location).

We have also tested this with a team member in Italy, and Firebase is returning the correct configuration for him. The location returned was Italy (no VPN but real location)

It looks like the country detection done by Firebase does not use the IP location as stated in the documentation. But then, how else is the location retrieved (my guess is using device real location/gps)? How can I simulate it for testing if not using a VPN?

The documentation says that the country is retrieved from the analytics data, and we have enabled all the data-sharing configurations to make this possible.

**PS.**
The results is the same for the iOS and Android SDKs. Actually, the data in analytics shows my real location instead the VPN location.

**Resume**
We tried returning different data depending on the country/region location (i.e: France) and using a VPN for testing.

**Expected result**
Firebase returns France specific data.

**Result**
Firebase returns default data.